# Project Euler #42 - Triangle Numbers

Tags: python, performance, programming-challenge, python-2.x

[Here](https://projecteuler.net/problem=42) is the Euler problem referenced, it says:

> The n\$^{th}\$ term of the sequence of triangle numbers is given by, t\$_n\$ =
>   ½n(n+1); so the first ten triangle numbers are:
>
> 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45, 55, ...
>
> By converting each letter in a word to a number corresponding to its
>   alphabetical position and adding these values we form a word value.
>   For example, the word value for SKY is 19 + 11 + 25 = 55 = t\$_{10}\$. If the
>   word value is a triangle number then we shall call the word a triangle
>   word.
>
> Using [words.txt](https://projecteuler.net/project/resources/p042_words.txt) (right click and 'Save Link/Target As...'), a 16K text
>   file containing nearly two-thousand common English words, how many are
>   triangle words?

My solution is as follows:

```
import re
import string

#generate a key to map the letters in our strings to
letters = string.ascii_uppercase
letters_map = {letter: idx for idx, letter in enumerate(string.ascii_uppercase, start=1)}

#open the file and parse on quoted values  
with open('words.txt') as f:
    words = sorted(re.findall(r'"(.*?)"', f.read()))

#max word score can only be Z*len(n), recall 'Z' : 26 in letters_map    
max_word_score = len(max(words, key=len))*26

#generate a list of triangle_numbers to search for using max_score as upper bound
n = 1
triangle_numbers = []
while 1/2.0*n*(n+1) <= max_word_score:
    triangle_numbers.append(1/2.0*n*(n+1))
    n += 1

#finally use a nested for loop to return number of triangle numbers in our now summed words
count = 0
for word in words:
    if sum(letters_map[char] for char in word) in triangle_numbers:
        count += 1

%%timeit
100 loops, best of 3: 3.67 ms per loop
```

I'm curious if there are any ways I can rewrite this with similar or better performance so that it is more pythonic. I'm curious about a few things more specifically:

1) Is it possible to rewrite this better using `itertools.ifilter` and `itertools.imap` using `letters_map` and the filter being the list of `triangle_numbers`, to greater affect than simply using a nested `for` loop and an `if` statement to filter?

2) Is my `while` construction extremely not pythonic? It felt awkward writing it the way it was and I wasn't sure what a better way of operating under that framework would be (needing to count up to some arbitrary ceiling, in this case `max_word_score`.)

3) Should I be getting in the habit of wrapping these items in mini-functions in order to make it more readable/replicable? Would that end up slowing runtime down? What sort of effect would that have in general.

4) Any other pythonizations I can use to better effect?

Comment: I think your while loop can be improved like this

max_triangle = 0.5 * max_word_score * (max_word_score + 1)

triangle_numbers = [ 0.5*k*(k + 1) for k in range(max_triangle)]

Answer (score 4):

Your should use `csv` to read the file.

```
import csv
with open('words.txt', 'rb') as csvfile:
    words = [
        word
        for line in csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
        for word in line
    ]
```

It's much easier to understand what it is doing. And it's probably safer and faster.

You define `letters`, however you use `string.ascii_uppercase` instead.

You can put `max_word_score` in the same 'block' as the while loop below it.
You can also re-arange `1/2.0*n*(n+1) <= max_word_score` to get the max n.

Python also has a style guide called [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), which says you should have a space either side of operators. `1 + 1` not `1+1`.
The only exception to this is when you want to show precedence. `1 + 2*3`.

You can change your `for word in words` to one large comprehension, and use `sum`. For better reliability.

```
max_word_score = len(max(words, key=len)) * 26
triangle_numbers = [
    0.5 * n * (n + 1)
    for n in xrange(int((2 * max_word_score + max_word_score)**0.5))
]

count = sum(
    1
    for word in words
    if sum(letters_map[char] for char in word) in triangle_numbers
)
```

If you also assume that you are not going to get the longest English word you can change `max_word_score = len(max(words, key=len)) * 26` to `max_word_score = 1909 * 26`, which will allow the second longest English word.
And as they are 'common English words' you could change `max_word_score` to `27 * 26`, which will allow the 9th longest English word.

And if you do use `max_word_score = 30 * 26`, then you can reduce the memory usage.

You should also change `letters_map`, `max_word_score` and `triangle_numbers` to uppercase variants, e.g. `LETTERS_MAP`.
This is as they are constants.

If I were to do all the above then I would use the following program:

```
import csv
import string

MAX_TRIANGLE = 30 * 26
LETTERS_MAP = {letter: idx for idx, letter in enumerate(string.ascii_uppercase, start=1)}
TRIANGLE_NUMBERS = [
    0.5 * n * (n + 1)
    for n in xrange(int((2 * MAX_TRIANGLE) ** 0.5))
]

with open('words.txt', 'rb') as csvfile:
    count = sum(
        1
        for line in csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
        for word in line
        if sum(LETTERS_MAP[char] for char in word) in TRIANGLE_NUMBERS
    )
```

If you want it to be faster than your original, then you can change `MAX_TRIANGLE = 30 * 26` to `MAX_TRIANGLE = 15 * 26`, bit dodgy IMO.
But this uses less memory, (unless `csv` loads everything into memory) and is more readable.

To answer your questions:

1. I would only encorage `itertools` if you use generators. Which you don't. (Well, you have one that is fed into `sum`...)
2. It's not 'Pythonic' as the maths you use isn't. However personally I think a greedy `for` is better, (hence why my maths is an over estimate).
3. If you wrapped them in a main that would be good. Wrapping them into functions, is always better than having no functions.
   But as this can be done with 3 constants, and 1 generator, I would say one function is fine.
4. I would say following [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) is your best bet for that.

Answer (score 4):

**Unnecessary floating point**

Triangular numbers are always integers. `n(n+1)` is always even because either `n` or `n+1` is. Thus you don't need to do floating point math here:

```
n = 1 
triangle_numbers = []
while 1/2.0*n*(n+1) <= max_word_score:
    triangle_numbers.append(1/2.0*n*(n+1))
    n += 1
```

You can simply write `n*(n+1)/2`. This drops your running time from 449ms (on 100 iterations) to 423ms.

**Unnecessary sorting**

You assign `words = sorted(...)`. Nowhere in your code to you need it to be sorted, so that's an easy thing to drop. That gets us down to 405ms.

**Checking for triangular numbers**

You're building up a *list* of triangular numbers up to the maximum possible. Logically, this is valid. However, we can do better. A `set` has much better performance for checking than a list does. Just making that change (declaring `triangle_numbers` as `set()` and using `add()`) gets us down to 321ms.

**Generator Expressions**

Generator expressions are actually slower than loops (fact), even if they're far easier to read (in my opinion). So when you really care about cycles, you'll want to rewrite your code to be:

```
count = 0 
for word in words:
    value = 0 
    for char in word:
        value += letters_map[char]
    if value in triangle_numbers:
        count += 1
return count
```

That gets us down to 222ms.

**File Reading**

Use [`csvreader`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.reader) to read in the words instead of `re`:

```
words = []
with open('euler42.txt') as f:
    for line in csv.reader(f, delimiter=',', quotechar='"'):
        words.extend(line)
```

Just using the more specific tool for the job. 172ms.

Comment: Great catches Barry thanks! I always look forward to reading your responses.

Comment: Also, and this is a guess a pretty in depth question. But is there any literature/good reading on why loops are faster than generator expressions. And what the difference between using things like xrange() vs. range() yields (no pun intended, ha) you in performance/when you'd use one over the other?

Comment: @mburke05 In Python2.7, `range()` gives you a list, e.g. `range(10)` returns `[0,1,2,...,9]`. `xrange()` is a generator that gives you each successive number on the fly, so it's far more efficient since it doesn't have to construct a list up front. In Python3, they fixed `range()` to do the smart thing.

Comment: @mburke05 Not sure of a good resource.